# Is there a keyword that refers to a member of a grandfather class in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

```
class Grandfather {

    protected function stuff() {
        // Code.
    } 
}

class Dad extends Grandfather {
    function __construct() {
        // I can refer to a member in the parent class easily.
        parent::stuff();
    }
}

class Kid extends Dad {
        // How do I refer to the stuff() method which is inside the Grandfather class from here?
}
```

How can I refer to a member of the Grandfather class from within the Kid class?

My first thought was `Classname::method()` but is there a keyword available such as `self` or `parent`?

Comment: Have you tried parent::parent::stuff() ?

Comment: I haven't tried `parent::parent::stuff()`. Do you have any further info on it?

Comment: it won't work @NomanUrRehman, it will casue syntax error like this: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)`

Comment: Are you trying to by pass the parent method and go to the unextended grandparent one? The parent class already includes all the grandparent ones but they may be extended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If `stuff()` is nowhere overriden in the class hierarchy you can call the function with `$this->stuff()`
2. If `stuff()` were to be overriden in `Dad` you have to call the function with the classname, e.g. `Grandfather::stuff()`
3. If `stuff()` is overriden in `Kid`, you can do the call via `parent::stuff()`

Comment: Your classes are extending from `Grandfather`, hence you inherit all of the properties of `Grandfather` - i.e. this will call the stuff() function in the Grandfather

Comment: OK but what if I had `function stuff()` inside `Kid`? I need to refer to the method in the Grandfather class. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Then you'd have to use `Grandfather::stuff()` as others mentioned here already. It's not a very clean way though in my opinion - what are your intentions? Perhaps a different design pattern altogether will give you a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Tyron, I don't have an actual project open, It's just something that I came across whilst reading an article last week that wasn't made clear and I've be meaning to seek clarification on.

Comment: Err ops, one correction. If you have `function stuff()` inside Kid, you can still call `parent::stuff()`. Only if you have `function stuff()` inside Dad, you'd need to use `Grandfather::stuff()`. In any case, I would design my functions in a way that `Dad` does not need to override functionality I would need in `Kid` but instead place that part in a seperate function.

Comment: Right! so to summarise... if the method inside Grandfather is overridden, I need to use the `Classname::method()` syntax?

Answer (score 5):

`$this->stuff()` 
or 
`Grandfather::stuff()`

calling with this will call `::stuff()` method on the top of inherit level
(in your example it'd be `Dad::stuff()`, but you don't override `::stuff` in `Dad` class so it'd be `Grandfather::stuff()`)

and `Class::method()` will  call exact class method

Example code:

```
    <?php
class Grandfather {

    protected function stuff() {
        echo "Yeeeh";
        // Code.
    } 
}

class Dad extends Grandfather {
    function __construct() {
        // I can refer to a member in the parent class easily.
        parent::stuff();
    }
}

class Kid extends Dad {
    public function doThatStuff(){
        Grandfather::stuff();
    }
      // How do I refer to the stuff() method which is inside the Grandfather class from here?
}
$Kid = new Kid();
$Kid->doThatStuff();
```

The "Yeeeh" will be outputted 2 times. Because constructor of `Dad` (which is not overrided in `Kid` class) class calls `Grandfather::stuff()` and `Kid::doThatStuff()` calls it too

Answer (score 1):

If you want call Grandfather::stuff method you can do this using `Grandfather::stuff()` in `Kid` class.

Look at this [example](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php#100005).

Comment: So you have to use `Class_Name::method()`? I suppose my question should have been is there a keyword available like `parent` and `self` when you're referring to more than one level up the hierarchy?